# Face selected in edge mode selecting

Tags: edges, faces, selection-tools, extrude

blender v. 4.0.2

I made a plan then extruded using E and the edges other planes next to it. These are supposed to be the floors to my rooms in my project. But then I selected the edges, using edge selection mode, and like you see, there's a face where only the edges are selected, and there's a face that becomes selected too, making it impossible de extrude only the edges (creating my walls).
Do you have any idea why? what could I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Selecft your edges then hit Alt-E > Edges to extrude just the edges..

Comment: By the way, while @JohnEason already told you how to only select edges: it is totally normal that a face is selected automatically when all its bounding edges (or vertices) are selected. And therefore I'm a bit surprised that on the right side in your screenshot the selected edges are not selecting the face... can it be there are duplicated separate edges (without face) on top of already existing edges? Otherwise the face they are forming should have been selected, too... to me this definitely looks like some issues with your mesh.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I agree looking closely at the image again. The unselected part of the edge down the centre looks darker than I'd expect too!

Comment: @JohnEason Yep, but nevertheless it is helpful to know for beginners that they can extrude just the edges even if there is a face between them so your comment is really good. I just fear there might soon appear other issues.